# Compile only floats

Tags: floats, compiling

When preparing a document, there are useful ways to limit what gets compiled overall. This is the case with the `\includeonly` command, and the `draft` option, that in many classes allows one to not include images to focus on the text.

Is there a similar option somewhere (or command) to compile only floats (figures and tables)? When preparing a large document, with figures and tables distributed over a couple hundred pages, I think this would be very useful. But looking in the regular places I couldn't find anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Package `preview` can be used to select the floats:

```
\usepackage[active,tightpage,floats]{preview}
```

Or more selective, e.g., figures only:

```
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewSnarfEnvironment[{[]}]{figure}
```

The result is a document, which contains the selected floats only.

If you want to save compile time, then there are other options:

- TikZ: `\usetikzlibrary{externalize}` for environment `tikzpicture`. The contents is written to an external file, compiled and included as PDF file. Details, see section "50 Externalization Library" of TikZ' [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).
- Making standalone images manually to embed then as PDF files.

Comment: The results are not all that I would have hoped for, but this does seem to be the answer to my question.